# image not fit in container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image, flutter-container

in this code i have to fit image into container. but not chnage any widget it is same only image fit in container.

```
body:
          GestureDetector(
              onScaleStart: (details) {
                _previousScale = _scale;
              },
              onScaleUpdate: (details) {
                setState(() {
                  _scale = _previousScale * details.scale;
                });
              },
              onDoubleTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _scale = (_scale == 1.0) ? 2.0 : 1.0;
                });
              },
              child: Transform(
                alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(_scale, _scale, 1.0),
                child: Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 5 / 7,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      alignment: isKeyboardVisible
                          ? Alignment.topCenter
                          : Alignment.center,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: double.infinity,
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 5 / 7,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Hero(
                              tag: "${widget.index}",
                              child: Image.asset(
                                "images/${widget.index}.png",
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                            ...movableTextWidgets,
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

what wrong in this code?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eia8u.jpg)
in this image black color is container and the white is image but not fit in container.

Comment: Have you tried adding BoxFit to image.asset or wrapping Hero in Positioned.fill?

Comment: could you please add the an image of the said container?

Comment: Image will get  stretched if container and image doesn't have matching aspect ratio

Comment: i add and update the code with image of output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and set your height and width to container

```
  Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
                   image: AssetImage("images/${widget.index}.png"), 
                   fit: BoxFit.cover),
                ),
              ),
```